# how to link taxnomies to node?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How to link taxnomies to node?

I've a taxonomy vocabulary and terms as follow

```
vocabulary1
Term 1.1
Term 1.2
Term 1.3
```

And I've a node (e.g node/123).

I want to link terms with node as

```
Term 1.1 => node/123#easy
Term 1.2 => node/123#normal
Term 1.3 => node/123#hard
```

I tried to change at URL PATH SETTINGS. but not working.

How can I do?

Comment: You need to add particular vocabulary to the content type and select the respective term when adding the node

Answer (score 0):

Go to manage fields section of the selected content type:

```
http://example.com/admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields
```

Add a new field, select field type as **Term reference** , select widget appropriately & save the changes.

After that this added taxonomy field will start displaying on node edit page & you are good to start linking after that.

Hope this will help.